# Verilog error says "invalid module item " and Invalid "module instantiation"

Tags: verilog

When I run the code, it says "invalid module item" and "Invalid module instantiation". I was trying show the output as truth table to verify my bool expression for my exam.

```
module finals_example (A,B,C,F);
    input A,B,C;
    output F;
    wire (A1,B1,C1,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,O1,O2);
    not (A1,A);
    not (B1,B);
    not (C1,C);
    not (D5,D4);
    and (D1,B1,C1);
    and (D2,A1,B1);
    and (D3,A1,C1);
    and (D4,A,B);
    or (O1,D1,D2);
    or (O2,D3,D5);
    and (F,O1,O2);
    
endmodule

module testbench;
    reg A,B,C;
    wire A1,B1,C1,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,O1,O2,F; 
    finals_example instance 0 (A,B,C,A1,B1,C1,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,O1,O2,F);
    
    initial 
        begin
        A=0; B=0; C=0; 
        A=0; B=0; C=1;
        A=0; B=1; C=0;
        A=0; B=1; C=1;
        A=1; B=0; C=0;
        A=1; B=0; C=1;
        A=1; B=1; C=0;
        A=1; B=1; C=1;
    end
    
        initial 
            begin 
            $monitor ("A =%b B =%b C =%b A1 =%b B1 =%b C1 =%b D1 =%b D2 =%b D3 =% D4 =%bD5 =%b O1 =%b O2 =% F =%b", A,B,C,A1,B1,C1,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,O1,O2,F);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few syntax errors.

Do not use parentheses around the signal names when you declare them as type `wire`.

Do not leave a space between `instance` and `0` in the instance name.  You likely meant it to be `instance0`.

You have too many connections to your instance.

A lone percent sign `%` is illegal in your `$monitor` line.  You likely meant to use `%b`.

Here is code that compiles without errors.  I marked the lines that need to change with a `/////` comment:

```
module finals_example (A,B,C,F);
    input A,B,C;
    output F;
    wire A1,B1,C1,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,O1,O2; /////
    not (A1,A);
    not (B1,B);
    not (C1,C);
    not (D5,D4);
    and (D1,B1,C1);
    and (D2,A1,B1);
    and (D3,A1,C1);
    and (D4,A,B);
    or (O1,D1,D2);
    or (O2,D3,D5);
    and (F,O1,O2);
    
endmodule

module testbench;
    reg A,B,C;
    wire A1,B1,C1,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,O1,O2,F; 
    finals_example instance0 (A,B,C,F); /////
    
    initial 
        begin
        A=0; B=0; C=0; 
        A=0; B=0; C=1;
        A=0; B=1; C=0;
        A=0; B=1; C=1;
        A=1; B=0; C=0;
        A=1; B=0; C=1;
        A=1; B=1; C=0;
        A=1; B=1; C=1;
    end
    
        initial 
            begin 
            $monitor ("A =%b B =%b C =%b A1 =%b B1 =%b C1 =%b D1 =%b D2 =%b D3 =%b D4 =%bD5 =%b O1 =%b O2 =%b F =%b", A,B,C,A1,B1,C1,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,O1,O2,F); /////
    end
endmodule
```